# HashSet "cannot convert from element type Object to Integer" when expecting a HashSet of Integer

Tags: java, set, hashset

In the following code I expect `pn.get(8).get(8)` to return an array of `Integers` (in this example length of array is 1, but in my program it's longer). Instead I get an array of `Objects`.

Can someone please tell me why and what I'm doing wrong.

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>> pn =
    new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>>();

for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
{
    pn.add(x, new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>());

    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        pn.get(x).add(y, new HashSet<Integer>());
        pn.get(x).get(y).add(new Integer(x));
    }
}


for (Integer i: pn.get(8).get(8).toArray())
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Comment: How do you know you're getting an array of objects? Are you getting an exception?

Comment: yes: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from element type Object to Integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the `toArray()` call in your `for` statement, which is returning `Object[]` instead of `Integer[]` as you might have expected. This is an artifact of how [Java implements generics using type erasure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure). A run time, the JVM doesn't know that your `HashSet` is of type `Integer`, so `toArray()` has to return an array of `Object[]`.

Thankfully, `HashSet` can be iterated directly so the `toArray()` call is unnecessary. The following works for me:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>> pn = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>>();

for (int x = 0; x < 9; x++) 
{
    pn.add(x, new ArrayList<HashSet<Integer>>());

    for (int y = 0; y < 9; y++) {
        pn.get(x).add(y, new HashSet<Integer>());
        pn.get(x).get(y).add(new Integer(x));
    }
}


for (Integer i: pn.get(8).get(8))
{
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `toArray()` , it returns a `Object[]` , while you loop variable is an `Integer` , hence the error.

```
for (Integer i: pn.get(8).get(8))
  {
       System.out.println(i);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

`<Collection>.toArray` by default will return an untyped (`Object`) array. To type it, that is to say which type to use (`Integer` in your case), use:

```
Integer[] integers = pn.get(8).get(8).toArray(new Integer[pn.get(8).get(8).size()]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens as a result of type erasure [(See oracle doc here)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html), which becomes an issue when you call toArray(). Because HashSet is an iterable collection, the call to toArray() is unnecessary anyway: You can simply use `for (Integer i: pn.get(8).get(8))`

Answer (score 1):

If you really want the array try this

```
    HashSet<Integer> temp = pn.get(8).get(8);
    Integer i[] = new Integer[temp.size()] ;

    for (Integer j: temp.toArray(i)) {
        System.out.println(j);
    }
```

Otherwise

```
    for (Integer j: pn.get(8).get(8)){
        System.out.println(j);
    }
```

will work just fine.